# Qual a origem da expressão "Ralar peito"?

Tags: expressões, origem-histórica, origem, girias

Entendo que a expressão "ralar peito" significa "ir embora" (ao menos no Brasil), mas qual a origem disso?

Exemplo: "Meu horário de trabalho é até as 17h, depois dessa hora eu vou ralar peito".

Encontrei duas perguntas sobre isso no Yahoo Respostas ([aqui](https://br.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20060712170933AA2jWID) e [aqui](https://br.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090313061338AAeLIkN)), mas em nenhuma delas existem respostas muito confiáveis. A versão mais aceita parece ser de que a expressão se originou no exército, do ato dos soldados de rastejar com o peito raspando no chão.

Afinal, a expressão vem do exército ou tem outra origem completamente diferente?

Alguém saberia responder? Se possível, com alguma fonte.

Comment: Sou do RS e sempre vi esta expressão como um _carioquismo_. João, já ouviste esta expressão ser usada em quais regiões do BR?

Comment: @gmauch sou catarinense e moro em Floripa, e ouço pessoas usando essa expressão por aqui.

Comment: Apenas como  complemento, posso afirmar que a expressão era bastante comum em São Paulo também (ao menos nos locais em que vivi). Hoje em dia não há vejo sendo usada com frequência.

Comment: a expressão deve ter sido criada por alguém que fazia surf sobre motocicleta kkk

Comment: Poderias dar alguns exemplos de utilização?

Comment: @JorgeB. Adicionei à pergunta.

Comment: Essa é uma expressão que ouço bastante no Rio, pouco em SP e acredito que se espalhou um pouco por outras cidades. Nunca a ouvi no norte ou no sul do Brasil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definição encontrada em https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/rala+peito/

> "No Rio de Janeiro, Inicialmente essa expressão era usada pelos
>   soldados calouros na década de 70/80 para designar o pagamento de
>   canguru, polichinelo ou Flexão (exercício físico realizado estando
>   inclinado, deitado para baixo, levantando o corpo com os braços e
>   retornando próximo ao solo). A ordem superior era imposta ao soldado
>   que era obrigado a cumprí-la o número de vezes geralmente expressiva
>   para que o tal aprendesse e não esquecesse uma lição. Certamente que
>   havia excessos nessa prática. Como o calouro tinha pouco preparo
>   físico, acabava não suportando manter o exercício pesado para os
>   braços e largava o peito no chão ralando-o várias vezes pois tinha que
>   cumprir a ordem pela disciplina. Acontecia também nos exercícios mais
>   intensos de rotina."

Answer (score 3):

Nas favelas do Rio de janeiro, olheiros, para avisar companheiros da aproximação de policiais, esfregavam a palma da mão no peito, sinal que os fazia fugir. Daí, por esfregarem as mãos no peito com frequência, dizia-se "rala peito''.

Comment: Luiz, isso é muito interessante. Sabes isso de experiência direta, de ouvir dizer, ou tens algumas fontes?